# clearing floated divs acting odd within parent div

Tags: css, css-float

- parent div = red dashed border
- child-3 el = green solid border

[code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris22/se3yE/4/)

The parent div (`#main-container`) contains, a headline, two floated divs and a text link at the bottom.   The text link at the bottom should stand alone, but it seems to effect the two floated divs (`.child-1`, `.child-2`) instead of the parent div. Can someone please explain to me why the last child element (`.child-3`) in this layout effects the contents of its two floated sibling divs?  What is missing and why is it needed?  Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/se3yE/5/?

Comment: yes, i'm currently looking at your code to see what is different...

Comment: I added `clear:both` to .child-3

Comment: yes, I see that now.  why was added to that element and not the parent container?  floats still confuse me :\

Comment: Why was `clear:both` added? You need that to clear the floated divs that appear before it.

Comment: @j08691, On this site [http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/], I read this information "_Just apply a class="clearfix" to the **parent** element. This is an improved version of the original, and documented here_".  I'm not using ".clearfix", but the "group" example is listed.  I guess I got confused

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by also adding the code into the OP.  Otherwise when the jsFiddle goes dead, this is useless to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without really looking into the issue and knowing what you want, placing `clear:both` on the `.child-3` seemed to work.

**Why?** http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: yes, adding clear:both to the last element worked.  I'll mark this as the answer, although j08691 answered, but no way to mark that comment as answer.

Comment: it's good to know WHY it worked too, I suggest reading that linked article.

Comment: @Phil, yep, I did ask "why" in my initial post. thanks for providing the link.

Comment: @Phil actually, I had already read the article at the link you posted.  It doesn't really discuss clearing floats according to my query.

Comment: This answer would be better if it summarized the key points in Quirksmode's clearing articles, particularly as they apply to this question.